# why the local host debugging still cross origin after using Http-proxy-middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to debugging in the localhost:3000 port when develop a react app, my server api address is `admin.example.com`, I config like this in the project `src/setupProxy.js` file:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/\/manage\/?$/', 
  { 
    target: 'https://admin.example.com/',
    changeOrigin: true
  }));
};
```

but when I start the app, still give me tips that the XHR was cross origin. what should I do to make it work? Am I missing something? this is the http-proxy-middleware version `"http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.1"`. the full request url is: `https://admin.example.com/manage/dashboard/overview`.

Comment: Have you changed the requests in your frontend code? Do they start with `localhost:3000/manage`? Shouldn't `'/\/manage\/?$/'` be a regex `/\/manage\/?$/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:
Here is the setupProxy.js file:

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy("/manage", { target: "https://admin.example.com/" }));
}
```

API request example:

```
app.post("manage/login", requireSignIn, Authentication.login);
```

Comment: You can use get/put/delete request too.

Comment: must using app post to send the http request?  @Jeniffer Jin

Comment: I tried your way, it works but it seems have 2 http request for per api, one is the cros error request, the other is the normal request. @Jeniffer Jin